# Why is setState() in a loop returning a Transform Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, eslint

I'm using React Native with Expo and this was working fine in my code but now it throws a `Transform Error: Syntax Error: Could not find Program`, and on debugging I found that the error is caused by `setUsers(user => [...user, users[key])`, apparently `React Native` hates this now.

```
useEffect(() => {
        setUsers([])
        const getEditors = async() => {
             if(currentUser) { 
             let users = await getAllUsers()
             for(const key in users){
                if((users[key].editor === "pending" || users[key].editor === "editor") && users[key].id !== currentUser?.uid) {
               setUsers(user => [...user, users[key]) //This is where the error is.
             }
                
             }
         
        }
        }
       getEditors()
 
}, [editors]);
```

This works in React JS without any errors or warnings

This is my solution to the problem

```
useEffect(() => {
        setUsers([])
        let storeUsers = []
        const getEditors = async() => {
             if(currentUser) { 
             let users = await getAllUsers()
             for(const key in users){
                if((users[key].editor === "pending" || users[key].editor === "editor") && users[key].id !== currentUser?.uid) {
               storedUsers.push(user[key))
             }

             }
           setUsers(storeUsers)
        }
        }
       getEditors()

}, [editors]);
```

Can someone please clarify maybe I'm missing something very obvious here. And if you can please refer me to where these changes were made where it's `Expo`, `React Native`, `ESLint` I want to learn more on this issue.

Comment: Its always better to have setter functions outside loop. Try `consr filteredUsers = Object.entries(users).filter(() => ...); setUsers((u)=> u.concat(users))`

Comment: I'll try that thank you. Do you happen to know why it throws that ```Transform Error```?

Comment: I have not faced that issue, yet. Also based on provided code, its difficult to relate. Its one of those bugs where as a dev you need to debug